# Polygon points out of letters

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfonts

For given font, and given string, how to get polygon points like these in the picture below, in JavaScript?

[image]

(I am aware of related questions on SO, but they are for Python or other languages/environments; I would like JavaScript only solution, if possible)

EDIT: Following up @Roman's the answer:

Using typeface.js online tool, I converted a TrueType font to typeface.js format. Each letter is represented similar to this: (here is representation of letter `d`)

```
    "d": {
        "x_min": 135.640625,
        "x_max": 792.171875,
        "ha": 928,
        "o": "m 135 998 l 330 998 q 792 499 763 933 q 330 0 763 65 l 135 0 l 135 998 m 330 151 q 648 499 635 211 q 330 846 635 786 l 287 846 l 287 151 l 330 151 "
    },
```

The key part of typeface.js code for rendering a letter based on this format is:

```
switch(action) {
    case 'm':
        ctx.moveTo(outline[i++], outline[i++]);
        break;
    case 'l':
        ctx.lineTo(outline[i++], outline[i++]);
        break;
    case 'q':
        var cpx = outline[i++];
        var cpy = outline[i++];
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(outline[i++], outline[i++], cpx, cpy);
        break;
    case 'b':
        var x = outline[i++];
        var y = outline[i++];
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(outline[i++], outline[i++], outline[i++], outline[i++], x, y);
        break;
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to write to a canvas and then calculate using some algorithm (which you might be able to borrow from another language), based on the canvas' pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some work has already been done for [typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/), a javascript library that replaces regular text with "canvas rendered one" (so you can use arbitrary font-faces).

typeface.js accomplishes this by using font definition data, which essentially holds the drawing instructions for each glyph. The data for the glyph "A" might look like this:

```
m 253 638 l 379 949 q 394 945 387 946 q 409 944 401 944 q 443 949 428 944 
q 565 629 525 733 q 673 359 605 526 q 822 0 740 192 q 773 3 804 0 q 736 7 
743 7 q 686 4 709 7 q 650 0 664 1 q 588 199 609 137 q 532 355 567 261 l 
370 355 l 210 355 l 159 205 q 127 110 142 161 q 99 0 112 59 l 43 6 q 6 3 
20 6 q -14 0 -8 0 q 74 211 29 105 q 155 403 119 317 q 253 638 191 490 m 
370 422 l 502 422 l 371 760 l 240 422 l 370 422
```

(I inserted newlines).

This string is a sequence of drawing operations with their respective numerical parameters. For example "m 253 638" corresponds to "move to x:253 y:638" and "l 379 949" being "draw line to x:379 y:949". etc, etc..

You should have a look at the source here:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~davidchester/typeface.js/trunk/view/head:/js/typeface.js

You could adapt that renderer to extract your poligons. The major trick here is to let [this page](http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html) do the hard work for you and create the font definitions.

Comment: I converted one font of interest to the typeface.js format. Let's see how typeface.js draws letters...